# JFree Chart with itext problem with font

Tags: linux, fonts, centos, itext, jfreechart

I want to use Jfree chart with itext to make a pdf. I have used custom font for JFree chart title and its other components using java.awt.Font class. It works ok in windows but on linux centOS, the title is overlapping with upper line and so do other things. Need help.

Thanks

Comment: Different system have different fonts with different metrics. Can you post a short example that reproduces the problem? http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. It's because the two platforms are using different version of java. On Windows its java (SE) 1.6 and on linux I was using openjdk. By making both java SE, problem's solved.

Comment: You should mark this answer as The Correct Answer... the little hollow check mark next to the answer.  It'll turn green.  That way folks with similar questions will know there's a good answer to be found under your question.